# HTML file behaves different in dirrerent servers

Tags: html, css, webserver

My first assignment in web programming class is to design a website without browser side and server side script.

I made an HTML 5 document, linked to a CSS file, all of them were validated in W3C validator, everything is good. I test the web page locally on my laptop on Chrome36, Firefox30 and IE11, all good.

But I'm required to upload it to University's server, all good in Chrome and firefox but IE, however I tried to put it on the server on my laptop and access it on IE from University's PC, it behaves all good.

### Apache server on my laptop, access from Uni's PC

[image]

### On Uni's server, access from Uni's PC

[image]

[image]

### My lecturer says I'll lose mark if it behaves so, what could be the problem and how can I solve it? Do server settings affect html's behave? Thanks!

Also, if you want, you can access it via [deakin.edu.au/~yshengk/a1](http://www.deakin.edu.au/~yshengk/a1)

Comment: Its the same URL accessing from an other client, right? Check your included Ressources like (CSS, JS, Images, HTML, etc.). I promise some external ressources will be blocked because of your UNI Proxy server.

Comment: I only included one CSS file, and some of the code in this CSS file works, I added a link on the bottom of my question, do you mind to check it for me?

Comment: We cant, its only accessible from "internal".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the html file can't see your css? Check file path's.

Comment: The checkboxes' and images' name tage position are defined in CSS file, so it can see my CSS

Comment: Your site in my browser is normal. Try Ctrl + F5

Comment: All browsers are good, my IE11 and Uni's IE10 are not, can you try it on IE?

Answer (score 0):

The only change I would see is the file and folder path looks different. Check whether you have used correct file/folder path. Try changing the CSS, JS, images folder path between relative folder path or absolute folder path.

Comment: I added / in front of the URL, then the blue background gone, the center alignment gone, which means it could find my CSS file, but didn't execute all